# Is it semantically correct to use ID scalar type for a foreign key field in a Type-graphql and Typeorm entity?

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

Here's the definition of `String` and `ID` from GraphQL's [documentation](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types):

```
GraphQL comes with a set of default scalar types out of the box:

String: A UTF‐8 character sequence.

ID: The ID scalar type represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key for a cache. The ID type is serialized in the same way as a String; however, defining it as an ID signifies that it is not intended to be human‐readable.
```

Would you use the ID type for the `userId` field in `Article`, which is the foreign key to the User entity? Or would you prefer `String` type for `userId` because the `id` field is the unique identifier for `Article`, not `userId`?

```
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Article {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "text" })
  title: string;

  @Field(type => ID) // <<= ID or String?
  @Column({type: "uuid"})
  userId: string

  @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "userId" })
  user: User;

  @Field()
  @CreateDateColumn()
  created: Date;

  @Field()
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated: Date;

}

@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  @Field()
  @Column({ type: "text" })
  name: string;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically the scalar `ID` makes more sense than the scalar `String` since per the definition it [`represents a unique identifier, often used to refetch an object or as the key for a cache`](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types). It is also not meant for human consumption, another part of the definition of the scalar `ID`.

The uniqueness of it is not really important from a GraphQL perspective it is very common to see multiple `IDs` in the same type. Using it is in fact encourage has it indicates to your consumer that it can (most likely) be used to fetch the full object.

Now you also have to challenge the need to expose the `userId` at all since this is a very "REST" way of thinking and it leaks the database relational model used, making it harder to evolve your data model without making breaking changes to the schema.

Generally you would only expose the `user: User` field as it already contains an `id` field. One might argue that it would do an unnecessary join, but this could be easily optimized with a lookahead. If a consumer needs user data, they will likely need more than just the `id` anyway so they will have to fetch the whole object from the database.